# Using ember-data with custom serializer

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have you could say a non standard json api. I'm trying to use ember-data with it so from my reading around I need to create a serializer. I tried to find article online explaining how to do this but haven't found anything useful. I tried looking through the ember guides but also found nothing. Here is an example of my api:

collection of data:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 14,
      "name": "company name",
      "slug": "company-name",
      "detail": {
        "data": {
          "id": 10,
          "address": "10000 sw 16th ct",
          "city": "Hollywood",
          "state": "Alabama"
        }
      },
      "employees": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": 17,
            "first_name": "Peter",
            "last_name": "Griffin",
            "email": "company-name@Griffin.co"
          },
          {
            "id": 18,
            "first_name": "Robert",
            "last_name": "Gornitz",
            "email": null
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "company name",
      "slug": "company-name",
      "detail": {
        "data": {
          "id": 8,
          "address": "1000 n university dr",
          "city": "Fort Lauderdale",
          "state": "West Virginia"
        }
      },
      "employees": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": 15,
            "first_name": "Peter",
            "last_name": "Griffin"
          },
          {
            "id": 16,
            "first_name": "Peter",
            "last_name": "Griffin"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is an item with its relationships:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "company name",
    "slug": "company-name",
    "detail": {
      "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "address": "1515 n university dr",
        "city": "Miami",
        "state": "Mississippi"
      }
    },
    "employees": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "first_name": "Peter",
          "last_name": "Griffin",
          "email": "peter@email.com"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "first_name": "Peter",
          "last_name": "Griffin",
          "email": "peter@email.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Are there any good resources showing me how to do this? Or should I just not use ember-data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just some tips from my side using Ember Data. I believe that you either have to be able the adapt api or write a deserializer:

**1. Root Key "data"**

Ember expects the root key to be the name of the model (e.g. "company"). You can handle that easily by creating an application serializer and overwriting the extractArray and extractSingle method by grabbing the payload from the 'data' key instead of the model "typeKey".

**2. Embedded Records**

You can use the EmbeddedRecordsMixin. But for that you will have to skip the root key "data" in the embedded records and directly include them (e.g. "employees": [ { id: "2", ... }, ... ])

I'd have a look at the EmbeddedRecordsMixin for that:
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html#method_normalize

Hope that helps a little.